# How to make style change happen before prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt

I'm writing a game that lets 2 players take turns playing. After a player makes a viable move, the blank element covers the whole screen and a prompt would then appear to ask if they should proceed to the next turn. The blank element will be removed to show the game after OK is clicked on prompt.

However, the prompt would appear right after the viable move was made instead of after the style change. So the blank cover would never appear on screen if the user clicks OK. The only way for the style change to happen is if the user clicks cancel on the prompt.

Is there some way to make the prompt happen after a style change?

Just an example code

```
var nextTurn;
cover.style.visibility='hidden';
function displaySwitch(){
     if(turn == 0){
          cover.style.visibility='visible';
          nextTurn = confirm("Click OK for next turn");
          if(nextTurn == true){
               cover.style.visibility='hidden';
               turn++;
          }
     }else if(turn == 1){
          cover.style.visibility='visible';
          nextTurn = confirm("Click OK for next turn");
          if(nextTurn == true){
               cover.style.visibility='hidden';
               turn--;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Set timeout is one solution but it is not blurt proof. There is some function you can run on element to force it to redraw itself synchronously, it is used when you need to apply css styles befor animations, but I forgot the name

Comment: The code calling the function is just an event listener to check for clicks on the page.

Comment: Personally, I don't agree with the `setTimeout()` recommendations. Yeah it's easy (possibly lazy) to wrap something in it, but that's rarely the way to go. IMHO in order to get an adequate answer, you need to include the code that is calling this function. More than likely the best approach is a callback or promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setTimeout with at least 50ms.
And you better use confirm instead of prompt because prompt returns an input value.

```
 if (turn == 0) {
      cover.style.visibility = 'visible';
      setTimeout(function() {
        nextTurn = confirm("Click OK for next turn");
        if (nextTurn == true) {
          cover.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          turn++;
        }
      }, 50);
    } else if (turn == 1) {
      cover.style.visibility = 'visible'
      setTimeout(function() {
        nextTurn = confirm("Click OK for next turn");
        if (nextTurn == true) {
          cover.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          turn--;
        }
      }, 50);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah my bad on the confirm/prompt thing. I had confirm on my real code. Just a mistake when I was thinking of an example code to illustrate my issue.

Comment: The time depends on your device performance. 50ms is quite enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using `setTimeout(() => { ... })`. This allows the browser to do stuff (e.g. rendering) before continuing your code. Note that you might run into issues if you have code after a call to `setTimeout`, so you might have to change a lot of code. (For example, [see MDN's docs for `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Late_timeouts).)

```js
let nextTurn;
cover.style.visibility = 'hidden';
function displaySwitch() {
     if(turn == 0) {
          cover.style.visibility = 'visible';
          setTimeout(() => {
              nextTurn = prompt("Click OK for next turn");
              if(nextTurn == true) {
                   cover.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                   turn++;
              }
          });
     } else if(turn == 1) {
          setTimeout(() => {
              nextTurn = prompt("Click OK for next turn");
              if(nextTurn == true) {
                   cover.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                   turn--;
              }
          });
     }
}
...
setTimeout(displaySwitch, 0);
```

Note: if you need to support older browsers and aren't doing any pre-processing, replace `() => { ... }` with `function() { ... }` and `let` with `var`.